# Have cards in columns listen to each other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm running into a frustrating issue.

I have a container, with in it one row with three columns. These rows merge to stacked on a mobile screen.

The content in the Cards, when longer than one line, wraps around to the second line. This, however, creates an imbalance. This will make the card text box with the longer text higher in height.

Is there any way to make the rest of the card text boxes adopt the height of the box with more text?

Also, any way to fix the obnoxious zero-line-spacing issue?

I'm adding a fiddle as we speak.

Cheers,
Anna

Fiddle: Note that you need to extent the width of the preview to Tablet or higher.

```
<div class="container content">
  <!-- Line-up -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h1 class="display-4 irie-red text-center">Dub Castle</h1>
      <div class="card rounded">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item text-center text-primary">Thursday</li>
          <li class="lineup fix-sticky list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">4PM - 6PM</p>
            <p>Chalice SoundsystemArtist Artist Artist ArtistArtist Artist Artist Artist</p>
          </li>
          <li class="lineup fix-sticky list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">6PM - 8PM</p>
            <p>Chalice Soundsystem</p>
          </li>
          <li class="lineup fix-sticky list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">8PM - 10PM</p>
            <p>Chalice Soundsystem</p>
          </li>
          <li class="lineup fix-sticky list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">10PM - 12PM</p>
            <p>Chalice Soundsystem</p>
          </li>
          <li class="lineup fix-sticky list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">12PM - 2AM</p>
            <p>Chalice Soundsystem</p>
          </li>
          <li class="lineup fix-sticky list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">2AM - 3AM</p>
            <p>Chalice Soundsystem Artist Artist Artist Artist</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h1 class="display-4 text-center">Main Stage</h1>
      <div class="card rounded">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item text-center text-primary">Thursday</li>
          <li class="lineup fix-sticky list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">4PM - 6PM</p>
            <p>Mo'Kalamity & The Wizards</p>
          </li>
          <li class="lineup fix-collapse list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">6PM - 8PM</p>
            <p>Mo'Kalamity</p>
          </li>
          <li class="lineup fix-collapse list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">8PM - 10PM</p>
            <p>Mo'Kalamity</p>
          </li>
          <li class="lineup fix-collapse list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">10PM - 12PM</p>
            <p>Mo'Kalamity</p>
          </li>
          <li class="lineup fix-collapse list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">12PM - 2AM</p>
            <p>Mo'Kalamity</p>
          </li>
          <li class="lineup fix-collapse list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">2AM - 3AM</p>
            <p>Mo'Kalamity</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h1 class="display-4 text-muted text-center">Open Mind</h1>
      <div class="card rounded">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item text-center text-primary">Thursday</li>
          <li class="lineup fix-collapse list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">4PM - 6PM</p>
            <p>Kabouter Plop</p>
          </li>
          <li class="lineup fix-collapse list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">6PM - 8PM</p>
            <p>Kabouter Plop</p>
          </li>
          <li class="lineup fix-collapse list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">8PM - 10PM</p>
            <p>Kabouter Plop</p>
          </li>
          <li class="lineup fix-collapse list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">10PM - 12PM</p>
            <p>Kabouter Plop</p>
          </li>
          <li class="lineup fix-collapse list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">12PM - 2AM</p>
            <p>Kabouter Plop</p>
          </li>
          <li class="lineup fix-collapse list-group-item">
            <p class="text-danger">2AM - 3AM</p>
            <p>Kabouter Plop</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <!-- Additional artist info -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card rounded youtube">
        <p class="text-center">Artist Info 1</p>
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 rounded-iframe">
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/49XqJQRKU-0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card rounded youtube">
        <p class="text-center">Artist Info 2</p>
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 rounded-iframe">
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/49XqJQRKU-0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/

Comment: I would like for them to be able to nicely adjust size so it's all on equal horizontal lines.

Answer (score 0):

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-layout

Bootstrap-4 enables you to get equal width and height column cards with .card-group or .card-deck, but as of 4.0-beta, these options are not yet responsive.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I could probably look into 'porting' it responsive though, right? if not, I can just tell my 'customer' (volunteers position) that it's not possible yet.

Comment: You might want to follow the development of this in v4-dev on github to see if they have made any forward progress on that. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap